# How to configure the Solr Datasource for Grafana?

Tags: solr, grafana

I wanted to be able to make some dashboards through collections in Solr. I have added the plugin Solr data source for Grafana, but my problem is that I can't see how to configure all the parameters ([parameters_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hQEh.png)) of this plugin on Grafana ! Any body could help me on this please ?

Regards,
Fares

Comment: https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/pue-solr-datasource/

Comment: I have already seen that but no guidance about configuring the parameters to be able to connect to my Solr !